# If statement to compare if lastName starts with letters A-L

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I tried running this code, but it doesn't work, can someone please help?

```
var lastName = document.queryselector('lastName');
var message = document.queryselector('message');

function checkFirstLetterOfLastName() {
 if (/^[A-L]/.test(lastName)) {
 message.textContent = 'Go stand in first line';
 } else {
 message.textContent = 'Go stand in first line';
 }
}

checkFirstLetterOfLastName();
```

Comment: This is not clear at all, what is `A-L` supposed to be ?

Comment: @adeneo a letter from A to L. Not sure why they thought even briefly it might work, though.

Comment: You should aspire to valid syntax, at least; I'd recommend a tutorial of some kind.

Comment: good time to learn about regex!

Comment: @nrmgy you should read first character of last name and check its character number(find out syntax and function on your own) which should be between 65-76... And yo... That will be done...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working example using regex:

```js
function checkFirstLetterOfLastName(lastName) {
  if (/^[A-L]/.test(lastName)) {
    console.log(lastName, 'starts with A-L');
  } else {
    console.log(lastName, 'does not start with A-L');
  }
}

checkFirstLetterOfLastName('Carlson');
checkFirstLetterOfLastName('Mathews');
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
 function checkFirstLetterOfLastName(lastname) {
  if((/^[A-L].+/i).test(lastname)) {
    console.log('starts with A-L');
  }
  else
  {
     console.log('does not starts with A-L');
  }
}

checkFirstLetterOfLastName("hello")
```

Comment: Isn't `.+` superfluous?

Answer (score 0):

```js
foo('Avery');
foo('David');
foo('Laura');
foo('Michael');
foo('Zachary');

function foo(x) {
  if(x.match(/^[A-L]/i)) {
    console.log('Go stand in first line.')
  }
  else console.log('Go stand in second line.');
}
```

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would use RegEx for this and use the `expression.test` method for it like so:

```
// a string that starts with a letter between A and L
var str = 'Hello!'
// a string that does not start with a letter between A and L
var notPass = 'SHould not pass'
// Note: this only checks for capital letters
var expr = /[A-L]/
console.log(expr.test(str[0]))
console.log(expr.test(notPass[0]))
```